# Facebook app canvas html?

Tags: facebook, canvas

I have a mobile app and I created for now a fake facebook app (with heroku), for have some permissions to use the graph.

I don't need a real Facebook App and I'm looking for a way to just display my html website in my facebook app, is that possible ?

In facebook developer -> Facebook canvas, I can set a secure canvasurl, but I don't have an https URL.

Any ideas ?

For resume : I just need a facebook app for have some permissions in the graph, but I just want to display an HTML website.

Comment: You _need_ HTTPS. // I don’t know what permissions you are asking for, and what specifically those should have to do with canvas - why can’t you ask for them in the mobile version of your app?

Comment: It's for game request, for invite friends not already in the app. And ok, https is mandatory